# Passing Cookies from Client to Load Balancer via Cloudflare Proxy

Tags: cookies, cloudflare

We have a load balancer that distributes traffic to a few servers.

In order to keep session integrity and some other bits we use a policy on the LB. Basically when a user hits the LB they receive a cookie that expires within 2 hours. This cookie tells the load balancer which server the user belongs to to stop them from switching server as they are progressing through the site.

This works fine in normal circumstances.

Now introduce Cloudflare CDN.

For some reason the cookie doesn't make it to the LB and it balances the traffic anyway. I'm assuming that there will be some kind of rule or setting within Cloudflare that will resolve this. Has anyone else came across this at all?

Cookie being used is jnAccel. It's value is a unique identifier as to which server that user belongs to. It's expiry is 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it would turn out the thing blocking Cookies was the HTTP/2 setting on CloudFlare.

You can find this in the network menu, It should be the first setting on the list.

The headers where scrambling and becoming non persistent with HTTTP/2.

If I find a solution to configure to load balancer to still enable HTTP/2 I will update my answer.