# Passing cookies from origin through CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare

Our organisation has a proxy configured through the CloudFlare as follows: The domain is located on the CloudFlare NS, using the A-record it accesses our internal LBs, which sends a request to one of the two servers. So the schema looks like this:

```
Client's request -> Domain on CloudFlare -> A -> Our LB -> Server
```

A cookie with the name of this host is transmitted from the end hosts, which is proxied by our LB through iRule. The problem is that when working through CF, this cookie does not reach the end user, which is why saving the session does not work.

`Server --*cookie*-> Our LB --*cookie*-> CloudFlare --*cookies are lost*-> Client`

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282121/passing-cookies-from-client-to-load-balancer-via-cloudflare-proxy), but disabling HTTP2 didn't help. Perhaps someone has come across a similar situation and knows how to implement such a solution?

I tried disabling HTTP2 and setting up page rules, but didn't find any suitable [rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427)

upd:

Without CloudFlare:

```
$ curl https://domain -kv 1> /dev/null
...
< cookie: hostname
< Set-Cookie: cookie=hostname; Domain=domain;Path=/; HttpOnly
```

With CloudFlare (missing Set-Cookie)

```
$ curl https://domain -kv 1> /dev/null
...
< cookie: hostname
```

Comment: Same issue. Did you solved it?